# In Python, how do I print only the final answer in a while loop when adding values between 1 and 20

Tags: python, while-loop

So this is what I've got. The output is every answer leading up to the final outcome of Odd = 100 and Even = 110. I was hoping someone could maybe suggest what I could do to only print the final answers rather than the whole list of iterations. 
Thanks a million x

```
#inputs
odd = 0
even = 0
counter = 0

# calculations for even numbers
while counter <= 20 and counter % 2 == 0:
    even = even + counter
    print("The sum of the EVEN numbers between 1 and 20 is", even)
    counter += 1

# calculations for odd numbers
    if counter <= 20 and counter % 2 != 0:
        odd = odd + counter
        print("The sum of the ODD numbers between 1 and 20 is", odd)
        counter += 1
```

Comment: yes sorry! it is python

Comment: so, remove the statement which prints the unwanted messages.

Comment: Sorry Michel, I'm a bit of a newbie at this. Which statement is the one that causes the unwanted messages?

Comment: As an aside, you can use `even = sum(range(2, 21, 2))` to get the total of even numbers and `odd = sum(range(1, 21, 2))` to get the sum of odd numbers... then just print those - that way you don't need the looping and incrementing stuff...

Comment: Thanks Jon, that looks very intelligent, but using a while loop is part of my assignment. I'm trying to get to grips with it before I can learn clever things like your suggestion!

Comment: Your while loop is exiting when the `counter` is 1, because the while loop says that counter has to be less than 20 **and** counter must be even. As soon as counter isn't even, the loop exits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the print statement after incrementing the counter, outside the while loop

```
 #inputs
odd = 0
even = 0
counter = 0

# calculations for even numbers
while counter <= 20 and counter % 2 == 0:
    even = even + counter
    counter += 1

# calculations for odd numbers
    if counter <= 20 and counter % 2 != 0:
        odd = odd + counter
        counter += 1

print("The sum of the ODD numbers between 1 and 20 is", odd)
print("The sum of the EVEN numbers between 1 and 20 is", even)
```

Comment: When I do this I get an answer of 0 for the EVEN, and 1 for the ODD. Feeling like such an idiot!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work; note the print statement is outside the while loop and the arithmetic is being done on odd and even using the if statement to determine which is to be added. Hope this makes sense

```
odd = 0
even = 0
counter = 0

while counter <= 20:
    if counter % 2 == 0:
        even += counter
    elif counter % 2 != 0:
        odd += counter
    counter += 1
print("Sum of odd numbers is: {}, sum of even numbers is: {}".format(odd, even))
```